# Custom domain in Visual Studio Online

Tags: dns, azure-devops

Is there any way to have my custom domain eg: code.mycompany.com point to my Visual Studio Online account mycompany.visualstudio.com?

I tried using a CNAME record but it's not working, (think it's maybe because of authentication against the domain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't currently have custom domain support in Visual Studio Online.  Feel free to head on over to [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5549714-allow-company-domain-integration-projects-compa) to submit the feature request though!

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano - thanks!  I updated the link with the new User Voice location:  https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services

Comment: This is a better link... https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5549714-allow-company-domain-integration-projects-compa since it addresses the question directly and not add extra submissions.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano great point.  I've updated my answer as well.